# MSBuild local binary different from build sever binary

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I have an *Asp.Net Core* application on *.Net Framework*.
I have tried to build the binary with `MSBuild` locally and deploy to IIS server, everything works fine.

But when I tried to build using remote bamboo build server, the binaries I got are not exactly the same.
And it shows *502 - Web server received an invalid response* while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

**1. Local**

```
Command: msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

MSBuild Version: 15.7.179.6572

Unique Binaries only shows in Local:

- Esent.Interop.dll
- libuv.dll
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sever.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.dll
- Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.X86.dll
- MyApplication.PrecompiledViews.dll

**2. Remote**

```
Command: msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true
```

MSBuild Version: 15.9

Unique Bianries only shows in Build Server:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Socket.dll
- MyApplication.Views.dll
- System.IO.Pipelines.dll
- System.Memory.dll
- System.Scecurity.Crptography.Cng.dll
- System.Security.Permissions.dll

Does anyone know why the binaries differ in this case?

Comment: Read the release notes and it is obvious, https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/releases

Comment: @Lex Li I do not think it's obvious. Can you write this as an answer?